# Fortran Cascading Polymorphism

Tags: fortran, polymorphism

I have two routines one calling the other that selects according to type.
`matc_a` calls `takano`. When I call `takano` from `matc_a`, would I need
so wrap the call to `takano` within `Select Type` or can I just call is
as follows

```
Case ("takano")
  Call takano (a)
```

There are the two routines

```
Subroutine takano  &
  (                &
    a              &
  )

Class (*), Intent (out) :: a 

Select Type (a)
Type Is (Real (Real32))
  a = atan ( Real(1,Real32) / Real(49,Real32) )

Type Is (Real (Real64)) 
  a = atan ( Real(1,Real64) / Real(49,Real64) )

Type Is (Real (Real128))
  a = atan ( Real(1,Real128) / Real(49,Real128) )

End Select

End Subroutine takano


Subroutine matc_a  &
  (                &
    a, strategy    &
  )

Class (*), Intent (out) :: a 
Character (len=*) :: strategy 

Select Case (Trim (strategy))

  Case ("takano")

    Select Type (a)
    Type Is (Real (Real32))
      Call takano (a)
    Type Is (Real (Real64))
      Call takano (a)
    Type Is (Real (Real128))
      Call takano (a)
    End Select

End Select

End Subroutine matc_a
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just use the shorter version and avoid the first type selection.

It doesn't matter whether you use one inside `takano` or not. The important thing is that it accepts a polymorphic dummy argument.

BTW, it seems to me you are emulating a dynamic typed language in Fortran. I am not sure, whether that is wise.

Comment: That's right. They will become useful later on. So using `Call takano (a)` within `matc_a` will also set the output type corresponding to `a` when I call `matc_a`?

Comment: The actual type of the output `a` must be known already when calling `matc_a`. You cannot set it inside in any way, because it is not allocatable or pointer. You can just use `select type` to find it out, but not to set it.